# Why does the status in onCharacteristicWrite callback becomes GATT_INVALID_OFFSET?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

I'm writing a byte array of data into a BLE device in Android. After calling `mGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristicToWrite);` The `onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)` callback method is invoked. If the write operation was successful status would have been 0 ie `GATT_SUCCESS = 0`, Instead of that i m receiving status as 7 ie `GATT_INVALID_OFFSET = 0x7`. Why does this happen? Can anybody help me. Thanks in advance peers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the peripheral running the GATT server is incorrectly written.

I assume you have a "long" value, meaning a value larger than fits in one ATT packet. Then the Invalid Offset error should be sent back in the following case:

> If the prepare Value Offset is greater than the current length of the attribute
>   value then all pending prepare write values shall be discarded for this client,
>   the queue shall be cleared and then an Error Response shall be sent with the
>   «Invalid Offset».

But whenever Android writes a Long value, it sets each chunk's offset to the accumulated sum of the previous chunks' lengths.

So just check what happens on the peripheral.